# Query returning 0 rows, even though rows exist - MySQL

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table called `parents`. It has a column named `share_src` which is indexed. Currently it is having 5 rows. Three of them have `NULL` while others have `post_4556` as their value.

I am running this statement -: `SELECT * FROM parents WHERE share_src != 'post_4556'`. It should return those three rows which have share_src as `NULL`. But it is returning `0 rows`.

What is wrong in my query. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `IS NULL` condition to fetch the rows where that particular field may be `NULL`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM parents 
WHERE share_src != 'post_4556'
    OR share_src IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your query, this is how [`NULL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) values behaves.

Add `OR share_src IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause, in order to return those that has nullable `share_src` too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM parents 
WHERE share_src != 'post_4556'
   OR share_src IS NULL;
```